# point on Line $x+y=0$ such that $\left|AM-BM\right|$ is Maximum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giMLE.png)** Let $x+y=0$ and $A(1,2)$ and $B(3,-1)$ . Then Calculation of point $M$ on Line $x+y=0$

such that $\left|AM-BM\right|$ is Maximum, is.

**[2]** Let $x+y=0$ and $A(1,2)$ and $B(3,-1)$ . Then calculation of  point $M$ on Line $x+y=0$

such that $\left|AM-BM\right|$ is Minimum, is.

Where $AM$ and $BM$ are Length of point $A$ to $M$ and $B$ to $M$ Respectively in each case.

$\bf{My\; Solution}::$ for $(1)$ one::

Here points $A(1,2)$ and $B(3,-1)$ are lie on same side of the line.

[image]

Using Cosine formula, $\displaystyle \cos \theta = \frac{(MA)^2+(MB)^2-(AB)^2}{2\cdot (MA)\cdot (MB)}$

and we know that $\cos \theta \leq 1\forall\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\displaystyle \left|MA-MB\right|\leq AM$

and equality hold when $\theta = 2n\pi,$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

But i did not understand how can i calculate coordinate of $M$

also help required in $(2)$ Question.

Thanks

Comment: What is $M$, and what are $AM$ and $BM$?  Is $M$ the coordinate of the point on the line $x+y=0$, or is a label for a point so that $AM$ is the segment from point $A$ to point $M$?  Do you mean the length of the segment by $AM$, or multiplication of coordinates of the point $M$ by the coordinates of $A$?

Comment: Thanks Jeff Snider.. Now i have corrected by question.

Comment: Have you learned how to take the derivative of a function?

Answer (score 0):

Part (2) looks easier since you want to find when $AM=BM$.  This is a straightforward algebra problem: $$\begin{align}M&=(x,-x), \text{ since } x+y=0,\\
AM &= \sqrt{(1-x)^2+(2+x)^2} \\
BM &= \sqrt{(3-x)^2+(-1+x)^2} \\
(AM)^2=(BM)^2 &\Rightarrow 
(1-x)^2+(2+x)^2 = (3-x)^2+(-1+x)^2.
\end{align}$$
I think you should be able to expand the squares on both sides and turn that into a quadratic equation and use the quadratic formula to solve.

I don't know how to solve part (1) without taking the derivative.  Have you learned that yet?  Here is my answer assuming you have:

You want to maximize $\vert AM-BM\vert$, which has the necessary (but not sufficient) condition $$\frac{d}{dx}(AM-BM)=0.$$
Using the formulas for $AM$ and $BM$ above, you can write out $$AM-BM=\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(2+x)^2} - \sqrt{(3-x)^2+(-1+x)^2},$$ then take the derivative, set it equal to zero, and solve for $x$.  Do you understand what that means?

You will likely have several solutions, and you need to check which of them is a maximum, a minimum, or neither.